# InheritableThreadLocal with parallel stream and AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am using InheritableThreadLocal in order to prepare data for thread and child threads.

```
static InheritableThreadLocal<SomeType> instance
```

Also, I am using parallel stream something like this:

```
someStream.parallel().forEach(this::doSomething);
```

Also, I am using spring AOP, which will be triggerd by doSomething method:

```
@Around(value = "within(package.SomeService+)")
public Object execution(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
   instance.get(); // sometimes value is null sometimes not
}
```

InheritableThreadLocal works fine everywhere except inside the AOP execution method. Sometimes instance does not contain a value. Do you have any idea why?
This is related to parallel stream if I set the value to the instance as the first line of the parallel stream function I do not have a problem. Do you know the reason or I miss something to do?

Comment: This someStream.forEach(this::doSomething); works?

Comment: But if `doSomething` is called in a different thread (which is a possibility when using an action on a parallel stream), shouldn't it be expected that `instance` will be of a different thread? How do you make sure that the thread-local is initialized in all those threads?

Comment: @dreamcrash yes, someStream.forEach works but I need parallel eecution.

Comment: @ernest_k If I understand correctly InheritableThreadLocal need to add this value to child treads automatically, I am able to see this value in all child threads in all methods except in AOP method

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic did you try with parallelStream() ?

Comment: No, I thought it is the same.

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic In theory, yes but I would tried anyway just in case

Comment: Please learn how to ask good questions using an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is way too much information hiding here. Where is the thread-local defined? How is it initialised? What does the intercepted method do? What does the stream contain? With an incoherent set of arbitrary code snippets I cannot answer these questions. Just give me an MCVE to work with and I shall be happy to answer your question. I am quite sure it is not an AOP problem but false understanding about how to do multi-threading with thread-locals.

Answer (score 1):

From the little information shared on this issue, I need to do some guessing:
someStream.parallel() will use the default Threadpool, which is ForkJoinPool.commonPool(). These Threads get reused. When using InheritableThreadLocal, then 'inheriting'/sharing of the values from the parent Threads only happens if the ChildThread is created. When the Value of the ParentThread changes later on, the ChildThreads, value is not changed anymore.

So I guess AOP is using the defaultThread pool as well and the ChildThreads are generated before you code executes and before you set the value for the parentThread (which is supposed to be inherited to the childs, but wont, because the Threads are reused instead of recreated).

Using InheritableThreadLocal and the default Threadpool doesnt make sense to me. You may want to look into using custom thread pools like this
https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool